# Type input with JS seems to remove the value typed when performing another action on the page python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Given this line of code that types an input using Javascript and selenium find_element_by_xpath method:

```
    self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','{}');".format(value.replace('\n', '')),self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("{}".format(xpath)))
```

When another action is performed on the page (eg click on another element) the value given with setAttribute disappears, does anyone know why or how to fix it.

PS. can't use selenium's send_keys() messes with the page I'm testing unfortunately
Basically, the setAttribute is somehow temporary, any1 had this issue anywhere?

This is the html for the element :

```
<input type="text" class="validate-input " placeholder="Introdu TOKEN" value="">
```

Comment: may be as workaround you can set attribute as last action on page, or at the time of you actually needs it

Comment: Yeah can';t do that really, cuz i need to insert it before the last action, it seems that waiting for some random animation to load fixed the issue, somehow while an animation is loading if send_keys does its thing a "continue" button is clicked abit messy tbh, thanks anyway